# "ls" works in cmd line but not in script for directories with space in their names

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls

I am a  beginner in bash scripting and I am trying to write a script which has as variables directory names, and who uses those variable values to run simple bash commands such as "ls" and "cd". It works perfectly fine when the directory has a "normal" name, for example

testfolder/folder01

But fails miserably when the directory has spaces and parenthesis in their names, which happens for example when you do a copy a subdirectory and paste in the same directory containing the subdirectory. The problem can be seen in this script:

```
[boblacerda@localhost MyScripts]$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash
VARDIR="testfolder/folder01"
ls $VARDIR
VARDIR="testfolder/folder01\ \(copy\)"
ls $VARDIR
[boblacerda@localhost MyScripts]$
```

This is the output of the script in debugging mode:

```
[boblacerda@localhost MyScripts]$ bash -x test.sh
+ VARDIR=testfolder/folder01
+ ls testfolder/folder01
testefile01  testefile02
+ VARDIR='testfolder/folder01\ \(copy\)'
+ ls 'testfolder/folder01\' '\(copy\)'
ls: cannot access testfolder/folder01\: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access \(copy\): No such file or directory
+ exit
[boblacerda@localhost MyScripts]$
```

As you see the first part, who uses a directory with a "normal" name works, but the second part, who uses a directory with spaces and parenthesis in its name, fails. The problem persists if I quote VARDIR in the ls command, i.e., if I use ls like this

ls "$VARDIR"

The output in this case is like this:

```
[boblacerda@localhost MyScripts]$ bash -x test.sh
+ VARDIR=testfolder/folder01
+ ls testfolder/folder01
testefile01  testefile02
+ VARDIR='testfolder/folder01\ \(copy\)'
+ ls 'testfolder/folder01\ \(copy\)'
ls: cannot access testfolder/folder01\ \(copy\): No such file or directory
+ exit
[boblacerda@localhost MyScripts]$
```

A final remark to add that the command

```
ls testfolder/folder01\ \(copy\)
```

works fine in the cmd as shown below:

```
[boblacerda@localhost MyScripts]$ls testfolder/folder01\ \(copy\)
testefile01  testefile02
[boblacerda@localhost MyScripts]$
```

Thank you all for the attention.

Comment: Too many quotes in the script. I believe `ls "testfolder/folder01\ \(copy\)"`  from the command line would also fail. Either escape the spaces *or* quote the string.

Comment: Why the backslashes?

Comment: You could try setting `IFS=$'\n'` in your script. Then it will only break if there are newlines in the file names. And if your file names have newlines, you could try `find -print0`.

Comment: Also, look into the differences between using the single-quote character and the double-quote character. When you single-quote, things are not expanded in the same way as with a double-quote. I know the double-quote fixed your issue, but it is important to understand why. Here is a decent summary. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29980/whats-the-difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-the-bash-shell/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ls "$VARDIR"
```

The double quotes will preserve the space, no need for backslashes.

Comment: VARDIR="testfolder/folder01 (copy)";ls "$VARDIR" works fine with me but whatever.

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I used 

VARDIR="testfolder/folder01 (copy)"

And it solved the problem.

Comment: @yellowantphil I didnt known and I just did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your script. First, you are not setting `VARDIR` correctly as you have too many backslashes. Second, you should put quotes around any use of any variable.

```
$ cat test.sh

#!/bin/bash
VARDIR="testfolder/folder01"
ls "$VARDIR"
VARDIR="testfolder/folder01 (copy)"
ls "$VARDIR"
```

When setting VARDIR, you can either use backslashes, or quotes, *but not both*:

```
VARDIR="testfolder/folder01 (copy)"
```

or

```
VARDIR=testfolder/folder01\ \(copy\)
```